# How to shuffle/randomize elements within EnumSet in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, enums, set

I have an EnumSet like this:

```
EnumSet<Fruit> otherFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(CURRENT_FRUIT);
```

I want to shuffle elements within `otherFruits`.

Is there any way to shuffle/randomize elements within this EnumSet? I don't want to convert it to List if possible. Can anyone provide an example as well.

I am using Java 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this without conversion to another data type like array or list. Internally `EnumSet` does not preserve an order: it just stores a bitmask of used enum constants. This way it's much faster and takes very low amount of memory.

To solve your problem you can use `ArrayList`:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>(otherFruits);
Collections.shuffle(fruits);
```

Comment: I see. How will I do this with List then efficiently? Can you provide an example if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sets don't have a modifiable order. You'll need to convert this to a `List` or other collection type that does.

Comment: `TreeSet`s and `LinkedHashSet`s, for example, do have a well-defined order.